# Is it possible to limit COUNTIF to certain columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

When I apply COUNTIF to a range that contains calculations, I get an error message.
To avoid that, can I also narrow the range only to certain columns?

For example, instead of `=COUNTIF($A$1:E;F1)` something like `=COUNTIF($A$1:A AND $C$1:C AND $E$1:E;F1)`

So that certain columns like B and D in my example are not included in the range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the columns with {} and separating columns with "," like this:

```
=countif({A1:A;C1:C;E1:E},F1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using COUNTIFS instead of COUNTIF with range and criteria as key-value pairs.

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A, "=" & F1, C1:C, "=" & F1, E1:E, "=" & F1)
```

Make sure to replace commas with semicolons for the formula to work in your locale.